# Unable to execute program using C++ IDE Codeblock GNU GCC compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, gnu

Good evening all and thank you for any help you can provide,

I have started off on my journey of trying to learn C++ and am struggling to execute any code that I have written. I have tried using both versions 13.12 and 16.01 of Codeblock and have also tried building multiple files. Same error message appears with all. Here is the sample code I first attempted with:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello\tI am your computer talking." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error message that appears when I try to build:

```
File  Line  Message 
            ===Build: Debug in SayHello (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===
1d          cannot find -1pthread
            === Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings(s) (0 minute (s), 0                         ..          second(s)) ===
```

Could anyone advise on a resolution? I have read conflicting solutions, such as somewhere in my computer a file is missing (1pthread?). Again, really grateful for any advice and virtual cake will follow my saviour. Thank you!

Miles

Comment: Have you written compiler options yourself? Have you mistyped -1pthread when it should be -lpthread? Notice small L, not 1

Comment: Yes you're right it's an "l" ! I know it has something to do with my MinGW setup. Working on it.

Comment: Thank you so much - it was a file missing in MinGW that I hadn't found because I was searching incorrectly!!